# Scoping issue with using clearTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am using setTimeout to run a slideshow. I want to have button to stop it. The markup is:

```
<h3> Modest Mouse at Fillmore in Miami <h3>

  <div>
     <img id="photo" src="http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/modestmouse3.jpg" alt= "Modest Mouse at Fillmore">
      <span>&bull;</span>
      <span>&bull;</span>
      <span>&bull;</span>

  </div>

  <button onclick="stopShow();">Stop</button>
```

The JS is:

```
var aSlideShowPics = ["http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/modestmouse3.jpg",
  "http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/modestmoude7.jpg",
  "http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/modestmouse8.jpg"
];

  // Timer for SlideShow

 var i = 0;
  function changeSlide()  {  
           var stopShowID;
           stopShowID = window.setTimeout(function()  {
              newPic = aSlideShowPics[i];     
              $("#photo").attr("src", newPic);
              i++;
              if (i < aSlideShowPics.length)  {
                 changeSlide();  // recursive call to increment i and change picture in DOM.
              }  else  {
                       i = 0;  // reset loop to keep slideshow going
                       changeSlide(); // Recursive call on loop end
                 }

              function stopShow() {
                window.clearTimeout(stopShowID);
              }
         }, 3000)
  }

 changeSlide();
```

I keep getting a reference error on button click of no stopShow. I've tried putting the clearTimeout function in several places in code but get same error. Perhaps a new set of eyes can see my error. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alank90/fLw2a4vs/). Thanks for any input.

Comment: Why is stopShow inside the timeout? That is your problem

Comment: I thought that was problem but when I moved it outside of changeslide to global scope and same error...

Answer (score 1):

Move the stopShow outside of the timeout and outside of changeSlide.

```
var stopShowID;
function changeSlide()  { 
    stopShowID = window.setTimeout( function(){}, 3000);       
}
function stopShow() { 
    if(stopShowID) {
        window.clearTimeout(stopShowID);
        stopShowID = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just did http://jsfiddle.net/alank90/fLw2a4vs/43/  and still get stopShow not defined.

Comment: because your fiddle is set up to run ondomready so the function is not in global scope.

Comment: Just to be clear I had it set in body to begin with and it still didn't. But thanks for input. I would appreciate who ever voted this question down to reconsider in light of this.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't launch your jsfidle example, so I update the content of your code, 2 issues raised:
1- Your `stopShow` was undefined, so I attached it to window scope: 
    window.stopShow = stopShow;
2- For your ClearTimeout scope issue: your `stopShowID` variable was inside your function `changeSlide`: your `stopShow` was using a local copy. I basically put it as a global variable so both function could have access to it.

```
var aSlideShowPics = ["http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/modestmouse3.jpg",
  "http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/modestmoude7.jpg",
  "http://the305.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/modestmouse8.jpg"
];

  // Timer for SlideShow

var stopShowID; 
 var i = 0;

function stopShow() {
    window.clearTimeout(stopShowID);
}

window.stopShow = stopShow;

  function changeSlide()  {  

           stopShowID = window.setTimeout(function()  {
              newPic = aSlideShowPics[i];     
              $("#photo").attr("src", newPic);
              i++;
              if (i < aSlideShowPics.length)  {
                 changeSlide();  // recursive call to increment i and change picture in DOM.
              }  else  {
                       i = 0;  // reset loop to keep slideshow going
                       changeSlide(); // Recursive call on loop end
                 }


         }, 3000)
  }


 changeSlide();
```

working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fLw2a4vs/44/

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was the fact that function was not in scope and did move out of local into Global scope but I still got reference error. But thanks to everyone here for the sanity check I needed on this. I would hope again the vote down gets reconsidered cause I already have the bots warning me.

Answer (score 1):

the stopShow() method does not exists at the window level, it only exists within the body of changeSlide().   Directly attach it to window

```
window.stopShow = function() ...
```

or pull it out of the closure

```
var i = 0;
var stopShowId;
function stopShow() {
     window.clearTimeout(stopShowID);
}

function changeSlide()  {  
     stopShowID = window.setTimeout(function()  {
         if (i >= aSlidesShowPics.length - 1)
             i = 0;

         var newPic = aSlideShowPics[i++];     
         $("#photo").attr("src", newPic);
         changeSlide();       
      }, 3000);
  }
```